# Copy specific files from a list located on a server to my folder?

Tags: excel, file, server, local, copy-paste

I want to copy several specific files that are listed in an excel sheet from a server to my local folder.
How to do the trick?

Comment: By coding. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Well, first you need to read the file names from the excel sheet. This can be done in many different programming language. Possibly, converting from excel to csv as a first step would make things easier (a .csv is a relatively simple text file, a .xls is a complex proprietary format).

Afterwards, you need to extract the list of files from that .csv or from your program. You could then pipe those files to "cp" command of other.

I hope this helps you get on track.